# Autofac System.Diagnostics exception

Tags: autofac

I am using Autofac 6.0 in a .Net Framework 4.8 based solution which has multiple projects in it.

During the startup Autoface is throwing exception "System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.5.0"

Throughout the solution, where ever there is reference of this DLL, it is of version 5.0. I have double checked binding redirection in App.config as well.

Once the solution is build, all the binaries are copied into a single folder. Inside this folder the version of System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource is 5.0

Not sure why Autofac is not getting this DLL with version 5.0 and looking for a version 4.x dll?
Is Autofac trying to look for this System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsSource DLL from some other path and not the current folder from where the exe is running?
[image]

Comment: To be clear, _Autofac_ is not "looking" for the dependency. There is no code in Autofac that goes searching. It may _require_ that dependency, but it's a runtime issue to locate it. You may want to expand your search scope to "how the .NET runtime locates dependencies."

Comment: Hi Travis, if my understanding is right, Autofac itself has a dependency on System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource DLL. So does it look for this dependency in the local folder from where the app is running or from somewhere else as well?

Comment: Autofac has the dependency, but it's important to differentiate _what's looking for it._ The .NET runtime is responsible for finding dependencies, and that's guided by the app type and configuration. The differentiation is important because it changes the question and how you search/fix it - don't limit yourself to "why isn't Autofac finding this," search for "why isn't .NET finding this." Look for [tools like Fusion log viewer to help.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer)